# Is it possible to save checkpoints in bayesopt in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, bayesian

In long training cases it is usefull to save intermediate results of training. Is it possible to do this with [`bayesopt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/bayesopt.html) in Matlab?

Or may be it is unneeded and one can just save latest best found point and restart from it?

Comment: Please [edit] the post to contain more information. It's not very clear what you currently want. A [mcve] would already go a long way, preferably together with what you already tried in order to get the intermediate results.

Comment: I think you just need to do that second thing. Run it in chunks, and use the intermediate result to start the next chunk. I'd still test it, just to make sure splitting the problem is in fact doable without breaking the algorithm.